# Ember-cli Pods & Loading Templates

Tags: ember.js

I have created a loading template for my application that is working and I'm now trying to create custom loading templates for my routes and I can't it to work.

Here is my file structure (using pods).

```
- app
- | pods
- - | application
- - - - adapter.js
- - - - template.hbs
- - | loading
- - - - template.hbs
- - | author
- - - - model.js
- - - | show
- - - - controller.js
- - - - route.js
- - - - template.hbs
- - - - | loading
- - - - - - template.hbs
```

Here is my router.js

```
Router.map(function()
{
  this.route('author.show', { path: '/author/:author_id' });
});
```

I am using

- ember 1.13.7
- ember-cli 1.13.8
- ember-data 1.13.8

How do I get a custom loading template for my 'author.show' route?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED!

I needed to re-organise my router.js to use the parent/child route format:

```
export default Router.map(function() {
    this.route('author', { path: "authors" }, function() {
        this.route('list', { path: "list" });
        this.route('show', { path: ":id" });
    });
});
```

- Route: **author** uses **pods/loading**
- Route: **author.list** uses **pods/author/loading**
- Route: **author.show** uses **pods/author/loading**